# Merge and replace values from overlapping matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have two overlapping matrices with some shared columns and rows:

```
m.1 = matrix(c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,1,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA), ncol=5)
colnames(m.1)  <- c("-2","-1","0","1","2")
rownames(m.1)  <- c("-2","-1","0","1","2")

##    -2 -1 0  1  2
## -2 NA NA 1 NA NA
## -1 NA  1 1  1 NA
##  0  1  1 1  1  1
##  1 NA  1 1  1 NA
##  2 NA NA 1 NA NA

m.2 = matrix(c(NA,2,NA,2,2,2,NA,2,NA), ncol=3)
colnames(m.2)  <- c("-1","0","1")
rownames(m.2)  <- c("-1","0","1")

##    -1 0  1
## -1 NA 2 NA
##  0  2 2  2
##  1 NA 2 NA
```

Now I want to pass the maximum value in each column from `m.1` and `m.2` to a new matrix `m.max`, which should look like this:

```
##    -2 -1 0  1  2
## -2 NA NA 1 NA NA
## -1 NA  1 2  1 NA
##  0  1  2 2  2  1
##  1 NA  1 2  1 NA
##  2 NA NA 1 NA NA
```

Based on previous threads, I have meddled with `merge()`, `replace()` and `match()` but cannot get the desired result at all, e.g.

```
m.max<- merge(m.1,m.2, by = "row.names", all=TRUE, sort = TRUE)

##   Row.names -2 -1.x 0.x 1.x  2 -1.y 0.y 1.y
## 1        -1 NA    1   1   1 NA   NA   2  NA
## 2        -2 NA   NA   1  NA NA   NA  NA  NA
## 3         0  1    1   1   1  1    2   2   2
## 4         1 NA    1   1   1 NA   NA   2  NA
## 5         2 NA   NA   1  NA NA   NA  NA  NA
```

Please help! Am I completely on the wrong track? Does this operation require a different kind of object than matrix? For example, I also tried to convert the matrices into raster objects and do cell statistics, but ran into problems because of the unequal dimensions of m.1 and m.2.

Importantly, the answer should also work for much larger objects, or whether I want to calculate the maximum, minimum or sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pmax`:

```
#we create a new matrix as big as m.1 with the values of m.2 in it
mres<-array(NA,dim(m.1),dimnames(m.1))
mres[rownames(m.2),colnames(m.2)]<-m.2
#Then we use pmax
pmax(m.1,mres,na.rm=TRUE)
#   -2 -1 0  1  2
#-2 NA NA 1 NA NA
#-1 NA  1 2  1 NA
#0   1  2 2  2  1
#1  NA  1 2  1 NA
#2  NA NA 1 NA NA
```

Comment: Sweet! That works perfectly @nicola! Thanks a lot. Now one more question: say I have 5 matrices as above, m.1 [3 rows/cols, value 5], m.2 [5 rows/cols, value 4] ... m.5 [11 rows/cols, value 1], and I want to combine them all together always using the maximum value. I have already tried your `pmax` procedure using two at a time (i.e. combine m.1 and m.2, then use that output and combine with m.3 and so one). Is there a way to combine all five matrices in one go?

Comment: In short: put all the matrices in a `list`; determine the max dimension and create a "pivot" matrix (like `mres` in my answer); fill the values with the matrices like the second line of the above (for instance `normalized<-lapply(matlist, function(x) {mres[rownames(x),colnames(x)]<-x;mres})`); then find the max of all of them (maybe something like `do.call(pmax,normalized)`).